# session->getFlashData shows more than once on view

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am using codeigniter4 and uses the following code

In the controller -

```
$this->session->setFlashdata('success','Your  Data is saved'); 
return view('dashboard');
```

In the View

```
 <?php if (session()->get('success')): ?>
 <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
 <?= session()->getFlashdata('success'); ?>
 </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
 </div>
```

As per  code igniter 4, this flashdata message should clear. But the  flashdata shows in the second page also. Then it clears on the third page.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter supports “[flashdata](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata)”, or session data that will only be available for the **next request**, and is then automatically cleared.

If you set flashdata in the first request, it will be avaiable for the second request and then auto-remove it.

It seem that you are setting and fetching the flashdata in same request.

Comment: It seem that you are setting and fetching the flashdata in same request. I am not clear on this comment . Would you please explain

Comment: Flashdata supposed to carry information from one request to the next request just for one time. 

If you set flashdata in a request, you use it in the next request.

Comment: Here i set it in the controller and then only gets in view once ..But it does not get it cleared it shows second time also .third time it does not show

Comment: One request equal to (one Controller method + a view). So if you set the flashdata in this request and getting it is same request, it is not counted. So even though you fetch the flashdata it will be deleted.

When a new request come after the above one. You can display the flshdata once and then it removed from the session. So on third request you won't get it.

Comment: Still i am not clear with the solution . What is the issue in the above code ?

Comment: Don't set and catch flashdata in the same method on a controller.